# How add items from collection editor to UserControl?

Tags: c#

[image]

I am trying to add a set of buttons to the UserControl

```
    public class SliderButton : UserControl
    {
        private List<ButtonMdr> list= new List<ButtonMdr>();
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public List<ButtonMdr> Items
        {
            get { return this.list; }
            set
            {
              this.Controls.AddRange(value.ToArray());
            }
        }
     }

// list.count  > 0
```

But when press Add nothing appears in UserControl

Comment: What does pressing Add do? Show us the code

Comment: @Haytam The complement of the code is fields and properties

Comment: But what happens when you press Add? Does it set the `Items` property?

Comment: @Haytam nothing appears